# pptp on raspberry behind fritz.box

Tags: vpn

I'd like to run a pptp vpn server on a raspberry pi in my home network behind a fritz.box.

It should work like this:

Android - internet - fritz - raspberry-pptp - internet

Client can connect, but no internet access.

1723 and GRE are open on fritz and should go to raspberry.

How do I have to iptable to make Android get internet via raspberry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the standard `pptpd` you need to ensure your client gets an ip address from the server and traffic forwarding is enabled on the raspi as well as iptables are configured correctly.

In `/etc/sysctl.conf` uncomment or add `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` to enable the forwarding of IPv4 traffic.
Now you can configure iptables forwarding with `sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`

Please note that the iptable rule will be deleted on restart of the pi so you might want to add a cron job to run it for you when the raspi reboots.

More info on this can be found here: https://www.domoticz.com/wiki/Installing_a_PPTP-VPN_server_on_a_Raspberry_Pi

Answer (score 1):

Previously I had used iptables to redirect 80/443 to Tomcat.
I had taken one of the many examples on the net (like [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/320614/how-to-forward-port-80-to-another-port-on-the-samemachine)) and fell into the trap that it forwards **all** traffic to Tomcat, so the VPN traffic, too.

The 80/443 rules must be [restricted](https://wiki.debian.org/Firewalls-local-port-redirection) with `--dst` to the public IP:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING --src 0/0 --dst 192.168.178.20 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```